# C# - Multicore threading for database intensive app

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, multicore

I have an application, which need to do some validation on the database end. Each process goes through database validation (search on the table that has around 6 million records), then goes through some Lucene Index searcher (the index is built off this 6 million record table). 
As these steps are disjoint for each line items being passed, I am thinking of utilizing multicore threading. (each of these lines take around 1/2 minute on a single thread).

What are my options with multicore in C#? 
Is there some good resources / third party library (I looked a bit at PowerThreading by Jeff Ritcher), some good tutorials.

I assume I need to do some thread pools in N core machines.

Currently, it takes around 40 secs to process 100 lines, looking to get this done to around 10 secs.

Thanks...

Comment: Is this just a duplicate? It sounds like it amounts to 'how do I write multithreaded code in .NET?' Searching on "multithreading [c#]" turns up a lot of useful information. For example, see the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100291/speed-up-loop-using-multithreading-in-c-question for a sample technique.

Comment: I somehow feel that SQL part is not optimized yet and it is early to start with app multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple [threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28VS.71%29.aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample3threadpool) should give you access to the multicore.  You will have to play around with the size of the thread pool, as your tasks look to have a lot of IO as well.

Comment: when you mean simple threading you are talking about threading pool? I tried threading pool in double core machine and still get around same performance!

Comment: Remember what Chris said about decoupling interdependencies?

Comment: I admit I haven't tried checking whether multi-threads use multiple cores, but that is true for Java and specifically noted as not true for Python because of a global lock.  Also synchronization and Amdahl's law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) will govern in any case.

Comment: Yes, multiple threads will be spread across all of your cores unless you explicitly prevent this.  If the threads work independently then you should get a speed-up nearly proportional to the number of cores.  If you're not getting that, something is wrong, most likely a global lock.

Comment: If the computation is independent and IO bound, you may be able to get greater speedup than the number of cores.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx)?

It is designed from the ground up for parallelizing tasks.

Comment: I dont' have enough bandwith to use F# right now. I will look into it. But, is there some C# solution you can suggest?

Comment: Keep your threads decoupled from interdependencies as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a factor of four speed increase and have four cores, all you need to do is avoid dependencies among tasks, which sounds feasible.  I think you'll find that you'll actually want to run more threads than cores because, at any given time, a number of threads will be blocked waiting for I/O.  Therefore, I suggest that, whichever method you use, ensure that it's easy to benchmark it with different thread counts.

Comment: Well, the simplest thing is to use the ThreadPool, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx.