# Help with Task parallel library usage

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to schedule a function call for a sequence of items using Task parallel library.

The following does not work

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach(var someValue in aCollection)
{
   var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(someValue));
   tasks.Add(t);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

But the below works

```
Task.WaitAll(aCollection.Select(a => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(a))).ToArray());
```

For the first approach it executes once and then stops. I am not sure if its overwriting the reference or something. Can someone pls. explain?

Also is there a way to pass some sequence number to Task that can be used to identifiy which task was scheduled first. I mean I want to wait for all the tasks to complete but then order the results based on the sequence in the collection.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956328/foreach-failing-when-using-parallel-task-library/3155693#3155693

Comment: @Jim: Thanks. Any idea on the sequence thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is causing execution to stop, but perhaps it's because you're [closing over the loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465115/problem-with-linq-anonymous-types-and-closures) here:

```
DoSomeWork(someValue));
```

You need to create a local variable and assign `someValue` to it, and then use that local variable, as is described in my linked question, like so:

```
foreach(var someValue in aCollection)
{
   var localCopy = someValue;

   var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(localCopy));
   tasks.Add(t);
}
```

Again, I've no idea if that is the problem to your deadlock issue, but that is one issue that will most likely cause problems.

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. Thanks. +1. How about the sequence thing? Any idea?

Comment: You can just use a `for` loop in conjunction with [this overload of Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235693.aspx). The `object` passed in gets assigned to [AsyncState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.asyncstate.aspx), and can be anything, it's completely arbitrary. In this case, just pass in the iterator variable (`i`) and retrieve it when `WaitAll` exits.

Comment: An example would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, your second question, I read it more carefully, do you mean you want to know which task was _started_ first, or which one _ended_ first?